# Unable to mock a method

Tags: junit, mocking, mockito, powermockito

I am new to JUNITS and have been trying to use Mockito and PowerMockito for writing some test cases for my code but have been facing an issue.

Class Code:

```
public class Example implements Callable<Void> {
    int startIndex;
    int endIndex;
    ConnectionPool connPool;
    Properties properties;

    public Example(int start, int end,
           ConnectionPool connPool, Properties properties) {
        this.startIndex = start;
        this.endIndex = end;
        this.connPool= connPool;
        this.properties = properties;
    }

    @Override
    public Void call() throws Exception {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        try {

            List<String> listInput = new ArrayList<>();
            Service service = new Service(
                    dbConnPool, properties, startIndex, endIndex);

            service.getMethod(listInput);

            .
            .
            .
```

JUNIT Code:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest()
public class ExampleTest {

    @Mock
    private ConnectionPool connectionPool;

    @Mock
    private Properties properties;

    @Mock
    private Service service = new Service(
            connectionPool, properties, 1, 1);

    @Mock
    private Connection connection;

    @Mock
    private Statement statement;

    @Mock
    private ResultSet resultSet;

    @InjectMocks
    private Example example = new Example(
            1, 1, connectionPool, properties);


    @Test
    public void testCall() throws Exception {
        List<String> listInput= new ArrayList<>();
        listInput.add("data1");

        when(service.getMethod(listInput)).thenReturn(listInput);
        example.call();
    }
```

Question: How to mock Service class and its method, getMethod, call ?

Explanation: The Service class has method getMethod, which is interacting with the DB. So, as I am not able to mock this method, the code goes through and then I have to mock all the objects in the getMethod as connection, resultset etc. else it throws NullPointerException.

Please help me understand what I am doing wrong and if possible provide your guidance on the way I should approach the JUNITS for this kind of method call.

Answer (score 0):

Mockito won't help you to mock an object if you have calling of `new Service` inside of your method.
Instead you need to use [PowerMock.expectNew](https://static.javadoc.io/org.powermock/powermock-api-easymock/1.6.5/org/powermock/api/easymock/PowerMock.html#expectNew-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Object...-)

```
Service mockService = PowerMock.createMock(Service.class);
PowerMock.expectNew(Service.class, connectionPool, properties, 1, 1)
         .andReturn(mockService);

PowerMock.replay(mockService);
```

For PowerMockito there is an equivalent:

```
PowerMockito.whenNew(Service.class)
            .withArguments(connectionPool, properties, 1, 1)
            .thenReturn(mockService);
```

Please check [this article](http://benkiefer.com/blog/2013/04/23/powermockito-constructor-mocking/).

Comment: The PowerMock is with EasyMock, but I am using mockito PowerMockito.
I tried: Service mockService = PowerMockito.mock(Service.class);
PowerMockito.whenNew(Service.class, connectionPool, properties, 1, 1)
         .andReturn(mockService); This is throwing error. Any suggestions?

Comment: It was showing a syntax error for that.
I tried the other solution you provided but it is not mocking the method call, and is still flowing through.

Comment: @AyushKumar do you get any error or it's just ignored? Did you annotate the test class with `@RunWith` and `@PrepareForTest`?

Comment: Yes I did. The application is a standalone java application and I have with PrepareForTest, but it still goes through to the class I am trying to mock.

Comment: @AyushKumar could you make sure that the parameters that is passed to constructor is the same as the the mocked parameters?

Comment: Please look at my code snippet, its in the same order as expected in the original class, else it would have thrown a compilation error.

Comment: @AyushKumar i mean, are you sure that in the code it is called with the same parameters? You are mocking `new Service(connectionPool, properties, 1, 1);`. But it won't work for `new Service(connectionPool, properties, 1, 2);`. All the parameters must match

Comment: Apologies, but I don't understand. How does this matter, both are int data type, be it any value. At least it should be able to mock. The test's result is immaterial at this point.